# Should I use value() or exists() to filter records in xml for speed

Tags: sql-server

Question #1: one can use `value()` or `exist()` method to filter rows. I want to know which one is faster.

Question #2: in SQL, we use `IN` operator like following :

```
select * 
from abc 
where abcid in (1,2)
```

Similarly can we use `IN` operator when dealing with XML?

Query #1:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (  
     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelDescription' AS PD,  
     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelWarrAndMain' AS WM)  
SELECT  
    CatalogDescription.value('(/PD:ProductDescription/@ProductModelName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM  
    Production.ProductModel  
WHERE
    CatalogDescription.exist('/PD:ProductDescription[@ProductModelName=''Mountain 100''][1]') = 1
```

Query #2:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (  
     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelDescription' AS PD,  
     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelWarrAndMain' AS WM)  
SELECT  
    CatalogDescription.value('(/PD:ProductDescription/@ProductModelName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM  
    Production.ProductModel  
WHERE
    CatalogDescription.value('(/PD:ProductDescription/@ProductModelName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = 'Mountain 100'
```

Yours sincerely

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The difference could come from your indexes.

A PATH index will boost performance of the exist() predicate on the WHERE clause, whereas a PROPERTY index will boost performance of the value() function.

Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522562.aspx

(2)The = operator of XPath 1.0 works that way, though XPath 1.0 doesn't provide syntax for writing sequences. So if you have an XML document of the form

```
<doc>
  <value>1</value>
  <value>2</value>
  <value>3</value>
</doc>
```

then an expression like `//doc[value = 2]` will return that doc element.

In XPath 2.0, the syntax (1, 2, 3) will create a sequence of three integers, and you can write conditions like `$i = (1, 2, 3)`. But literal sequences are not a feature of XPath 1.0 -- the only way to get multiple values on one side of an XPath expression is to use a path expression that matches multiple nodes.

Comment: well, i wanted to shred the xml using node(/doc/value) , in this way i will get three rows , after that ,i want to get 2 and 3 but not 1, how can i get it using xml.